# "Error: Account does not exist or has no data" when i use wallet.signAllTransactions(transactions) at once

Tags: transactions

[image]

[image]

i don't know why i had run this code "await wallet.signAllTransactions(transactions)" and approve in my wallet, transaction is successed. My account should be created but it doesn't work. when i fetch data from account i receive Error: Account does not exist or has no data. I don't know what am I doing wrong in logic?
if i use "const tx = await provider.sendAndConfirm(transaction)" in comment, it still working normally and the account is still created

Answer (score 1):

If the transactions depend on each other, for example, if the first transaction creates an account and the second transaction uses that account, then the second transaction may fail if the validator executes it before the first transaction.

This is an issue because `sendAllTransactions` should send all transactions at the same time.

So in your case (maybe), you'll need to confirm the transactions one by one as in your comment.